# Color function for ListPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

I have an array of the following form `{{a_n,b_n,c_n}}` where `n` is quite large. I wish to plot `a_n` against `b_n` using `Listplot` with `c_n` specifying a `ColorFunction` perhaps `Hue[]` how would I go about this? 
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do that using Point and VertexColors:

```
data = {{1, 2, 0}, {2, 1, 0.5}, {3, 1.3, 0.6}, {4, 1.1, 0.8}};
Graphics[
 Point[data[[All, ;; 2]],VertexColors -> (Hue /@ data[[All, 3]])],
 Frame -> True, 
 ImageSize -> 400
]
```

[image]

This should be very good in terms of memory as you only have one Point object.

Answer (score 4):

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {100, 3}];

rng = MinMax@data[[All, 3]];

Legended[
 Graphics[
  {AbsolutePointSize[5],
   {ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#[[3]], rng]],
      Tooltip[Point[#[[1 ;; 2]]], #[[3]]]} & /@
    data},
  Frame -> True,
  ImageSize -> 400,
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"a", "b"})],
 BarLegend[{"Rainbow", rng}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = Round[RandomReal[5, {20, 3}], .01];
```

You can use your 3D data as input to `BubbleChart` with the option `ColorFunction -> (Hue[#3] &)`:

```
BubbleChart[data, ColorFunction -> (Hue[#3] &), 
 BubbleSizes -> {.03, .03}, 
 ChartLegends -> SwatchLegend[Hue /@ Rescale[Union[data[[All, -1]]]], 
   Union[data[[All, -1]]], LegendMarkers -> "Bubble"]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can wrap each point with `List` and `ListPlot` with the option `PlotStyle`:

```
ListPlot[List /@ data[[All, {1, 2}]], 
 PlotStyle -> (Hue /@ Rescale[data[[All, -1]]]), 
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[.03], ImageSize -> Medium, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 Frame -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[Union[styles], Union@data[[All, -1]], 
   LegendMarkers -> "Bubble"]]
```

[image]

Comment: In terms of memory both are not very ideal: For a 100 points the bubblechart is 272664 bytes, the listplot 1086800, and my solution with vertexcolor just 9344 bytes. (i removed the legend from both).

Comment: @SHuisman, very good point. Got distracted with `ListPlot` and `ColorFunction` and missed the _large n_ bit.

Comment: 'quite large' could mean 100 or 10^8 so I'm not sure about the importance… But both ListPlot and BubbleChart have a lot of overhead.